# FabricJS layers

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Initially, an object (`fabric.Circle`) is added to my canvas.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
var circle = new fabric.Circle ({
    radius: 100,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});
canvas.add(circle);
```

Now if I use a button to add another object to my canvas, the previous one disappears. I reckon it adds the new object on top of the previous layer.

I don't want that. Is there any way to keep adding objects to the current layer without losing the FabricJS's functionalities?

Edit: The button and its corresponding function are as follows:

```
<button onclick="addArrowToCanvas()">Add Circle</button>
<script>
                function addArrowToCanvas(){
                    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
                    var circle = new fabric.Circle ({
                        radius: 100,
                        fill: 'white',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        originX: 'center',
                        originY: 'center'
                    });
                    canvas.add(circle);
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: On the same canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that indeed adds the other object on top of the previous one, as you didn't specify the position for the object when creating it.

You need to set different positions *(top, left)* for each individual object as per your need, so that they don't overlap each other.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
   top: 50,  //<-- set this
   left: 50,  //<-- set this
   radius: 30,
   fill: 'white',
   stroke: 'black',
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center'
});
canvas.add(circle);

function addRect() {
   var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      top: 120,  //<-- set this
      left: 120,  //<-- set this
      width: 60,
      height: 60,
      fill: 'white',
      stroke: 'black',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
   })
   canvas.add(rect);
}
```

```css
body{margin:10px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden}canvas {border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
<button onclick="addRect()">Add Rectangle</button>
```